# Getting a SSL/TLS certificate for GRPC services from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, ssl-certificate, grpc

I wrote a GRPC service. This is my server code:

```
type GrpcServer[TServer any] func(*Handler) TServer

type GrpcRegistrar[TServer any] func(grpc.ServiceRegistrar, TServer)

type GrpcService[TServer any] struct {
    handler         *Handler
    inner           GrpcServer[TServer]
    registrar       GrpcRegistrar[TServer]
    certificateFile string
    certificateKey  string
    addr            string
    clientAddr      string
    gatewayAddr     string
}

func (service *GrpcService[TServer]) runGRPC(lis net.Listener, opts ...grpc.ServerOption) (*grpc.Server, error) {

    creds, err := credentials.NewServerTLSFromFile(service.certificateFile, service.certificateKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, service.handler.Logger.Error(err, "Failed to setup TLS")
    }

    opts = append([]grpc.ServerOption{grpc.Creds(creds)}, opts...)
    server := grpc.NewServer(opts...)

    service.registrar(server, service.inner(service.handler))

    service.handler.Logger.Log("GRPC listening on %s", service.addr)
    if err := server.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        return nil, service.handler.Logger.Error(err, "GRPC server failed unrecoverably")
    }

    return server, nil
}
```

The issue I'm having is that this service expects a certificate file and certificate key. I understand I can create a public certificate using AWS credential manager and download it using the AWS CLI. However, this only gives me the certificate value; I need a key file in addition. Is there a way I can get a certificate from AWS for use as GRPC server credentials?